# VS2012 Web Deploy Package to create application pool

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

I have a web application project in VS2012 which I'm publishing using a "Web Deploy Package". I want this package to include app-pool settings, specifically *creating* an IIS app-pool and assigning the newly created application to it.

I'm familiar with the option "Include application pool settings used by this Web project" available when the project is configured to use an IIS instance (not IIS Express), but IIS configuration is **not** part of the project file, and thus not source controlled. What happens when somebody builds a deployment package on a machine that hasn't had IIS meticulously configured? Not ideal.

How else then, can I go about getting AppPool settings into my web deploy package? I understand that the appPoolConfig provider is IIS7+ only, I'm fine with that limitation. I've banged my head against this issue in the past and never found a solution. 18 months later, we've got a new VisualStudio version, and a new web-publishing-pipeline, are there new options to address this? Or maybe something I missed when I first tackled this problem?

**Edit**

OK, I'm seeing the following as options:

1. Configure my project to sync settings from an IIS instance. As mentioned, I'm not a fan of this given that it puts settings *outside* of the project, meaning the environment has to be meticulously configured to build + publish. Plus it drags along other IIS settings I don't want included.
2. Inject something into the web-publishing-pipeline (WPP) to modify the archive.xml. I've toyed with this in the past and had limited success. One problem is the pipeline isn't exactly co-operative with working directly on the archive.xml file, another problem is some of the more cryptic attributes involved, like `MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions` which appears to have some Base64 encoded binary? No idea what to put in there.
3. Find an existing "provider" that can do what I want. I might be out of luck here, the `appPoolConfig` provider only seems to want to read / write IIS, not, say, an XML file of settings. Does anybody know otherwise?
4. Write my own "provider" to produce manifest output entries. I'm not sure, is it possible to write a custom provider that writes to a manifest using the name of an existing provider? As in, `MyCustomPoolProvider` writes `appPoolConfig` sections into a manifest? This sounds like a potentially painful exercise that may or may not work. Would I still need to figure out the encoding of whatever is going into `MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions`?

I get the feeling that the fundamental obstacle with Web Deploy for what I'm trying to accomplish, is how strictly it leans on "providers". The pre-existing providers are largely designed for IIS synchronisation, **not** primary development and publication. It so happens that some of these providers can be *relatively* easily hooked into via MSBuild, but the majority insist on pulling data from IIS, and that's that.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your understanding of the `appPoolConfig` provider, in that it can only sync between App Pools and can't be provided with the configuration directly. What you could potentially do is keep a copy of the appPool in question in `package` form (ie. `msdeploy -verb:sync -source:appPoolConfig=PoolName -dest:package=apppool.zip`) and attempt to hijack the pipeline so that the MSDeploy call adds the application content into the package, leaving the existing content there.

Alternatively, you could always keep the packages separate and deploy them with different calls to MSDeploy.

FYI, `MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions` is simply an encoded version of the parameters supplied to the provider when it was packaged. For example, `-source:dirPath=c:\,ignoreErrors=0x10293847 -dest:package=package.zip` would package the `ignoreErrors` value.

Comment: Any clues on the encoding pattern for `MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions`? Not that it's something one could easily inject into the WPP pipeline, but being able to directly adjust the contents of `archive.xml` would grant a lot of flexibility. Forget about providers, one could just make a tool that generates the necessary xml, bundles it, and you're good to deploy.

Comment: The format of the bundled archive.xml is undefined. However, you could potentially inject your elements (minus MSDeployProviderOptions) directly into the source manifest *before* the WPP calls MSDeploy.

Comment: The source manifest needs to be a collection of provider *read* options though doesn't it? As in, an appPoolConfig section in a source manifest is still going to try and read from IIS, that's just the nature of the provider.

Comment: @Snixtor - Yes, but you could keep a package (or archiveDir) that contains your appPool config (previously synced from IIS but committed to SVN). After WPP has created the package, you could sync the package/archiveDir into WPP's package to add the archiveDir. You'll need to make sure your WPP parameters aren't cleared, but it's an avenue worth persuing.